# TypeError while testing answer checker

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, python-behave

I'm writing a test for my "answer checker", so I made a test question and I want to test if the result checker works by giving the right answer (so the test should pass).

I'm in some trouble with the error that I got back. I know the code it's not that good, but I'm new in this field. I think I've misunderstood something in the logic. Can anybody help? :)

Error is:

```
correct = QuestionMultipleChoice.correct_answer()
      TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Test (the last lines are wrong I know):

```
@when(u'I give an answer to a Multiple choice question')
def save_object(context):
    lab1 = Lab.objects.create(lab_name="testlab", pub_date=datetime.now(), lab_theory="test theory")
    question1 = QuestionMultipleChoice.objects.create(lab=lab1, question='This is a test question', option1='1', option2='2', option3='3', option4='4', answer=1)        

@then(u'I should get true if answer is correct')
def should_have_only_one_object(self):
    given = 1
    correct = QuestionMultipleChoice.correct_answer()
    QuestionMultipleChoice.check_answer(correct, given)
    assert 1 == Lab.objects.count()
```

Models.py

```
class QuestionMultipleChoice(models.Model):
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = QuestionType.multiplechoice
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    answer = models.IntegerField(max_length=200,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    @property
    def html_name(self):
        return "q_mc_{}".format(self.pk)

    @property
    def correct_answer(self):
        correct_answer_number = int(self.answer)
        correct_answer = getattr(self, "option{}".format(correct_answer_number))
        return correct_answer

    def check_answer(self, given):
        return self.correct_answer == given
```

**Update:**

I made some changes, and now the code looks like this:

```
def test_check_wrong_answer(self):
        given=2
        lab1= Lab.objects.create(lab_name="testlab", pub_date=datetime.now(), lab_theory="test theory")
        question1 = QuestionMultipleChoice.objects.create(lab=lab1, question='This is a test question', option1='1', option2='2', option3='3', option4='4', answer=1)
        answer = question1.correct_answer
        self.assertTrue(question1.check_answer(given))
        self.assertEqual(Lab.objects.count(), 1)
```

BUT, test still fails with:

```
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Comment: `correct_answer` is a `property` of an object of type `QuestionMultipleChoice`, if you want to access to `correct_answer` directly from the class you have to define `correct_answer` as a static method by using  `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: see the comment from Messaoud Zahi, and also - create an object of QuestionMultipleChoice before accessing its properties and methods.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the parenthesis after `correct_answer` as it is a property, not a method.

Try:

```
@then(u'I should get true if answer is correct')
def should_have_only_one_object(self):
    given = 1
    correct = QuestionMultipleChoice().correct_answer
    QuestionMultipleChoice.check_answer(correct, given)
    assert 1 == Lab.objects.count()
```

#### Update

Here is an easy implementation using django's TestCase.
[See more in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/)

```
from django.tests import TestCase


class QuestionTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.lab = Lab.objects.create(lab_name="testlab", pub_date=datetime.now(), lab_theory="test theory")
        cls.question = QuestionMultipleChoice.objects.create(lab=lab1, question='This is a test question', option1='1', option2='2', option3='3', option4='4', answer=1)
        cls.answer = cls.question.correct_answer
    
    def test_check_answer(given=1):
        self.assertTrue(self.question.check_answer(self.answer, given))
    
    def test_lab_count():
        self.assertEqual(Lab.objects.count(), 1)
```

Comment: also he needs to create an object of QuestionMultipleChoice and not access directly from class.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time! Unfurtunatelly i still have some errors (again the same). I think @Som-1 is right, but how can i create an object here? I mean i know how but i've a method in my test where i already create objects, so how can i access it from here?

Comment: Store it as a property of some of common objects. For unit tests it usually a TestCase class which creates and stores common data for tests and has setup and teardown methods for that. In your case it might be testing client, or context, or other class, containing your test steps.

Comment: Thank you very much that helped, thank you everybody :)

Comment: Hi Dan, i was checking the test result. The execution is correct, but test fails: "AssertionError: False is not true" .